# AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials. AuthFailed only at SPECIFIC regions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am trying to perform some actions via linux aws CLI. My credentials file is 100% correct.

User has EC2FullAccess and Amdinistrative(highest rank) permissions. I am able to execute all commands.

The problem is that following regions produce AuthFailed error, rest regions work fine:

- Ohio
- Central
- Frankfurt
- Seoul
- London.

Those regions are all available to my account via web interface, and also `aws ec2 describe-regions` prints all of regions.

Creating instances, for example, via web interface in specified regions works fine as well.

Date of linux box that I use to access aws cli is set to it's hardware clock with only difference in clock format. Hardware clock is 12, while date command shows in 24 format.

----------------------Update---------------------------------

As i have just found problem is with Signature 4. 
Here is the problem:

> ""SignatureVersion":["2"] Signature Version 2 is not supported in
>   regions that initially came into service in 2014 or later, which
>   currently includes ap-northeast-2 and eu-central-1, as well as China.
>   All regions support Signature Version 4, and newer regions only
>   support V4.
>   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html
>   "

But how do I use SignatureVersion 4 only via cli for my requests?

Comment: Sanity check: Try updating to the latest version of the AWS CLI.  Your installed AWS CLI may not be able to handle v4 signatures. An up-to-date CLI should be able to resolve the signature correctly on its own.

Answer (score 2):

Try updating to the latest version of the AWS CLI. Your installed AWS CLI may not be able to handle v4 signatures.

Per the documentation:

> For all AWS regions, AWS SDKs use Signature Version 4 by default to
>   authenticate requests. When using AWS SDKs that were released before
>   May 2016, you may be required to request Signature Version 4

To check your current CLI version: `aws --version`